# Auto Open URL With Delay

Tags: jquery, delay

When I load the page with my urls, the code is open all at once. For example: I have 5 urls, loading the page, the 5 urls are opened.

How do I open the first one, after which the second and third, fourth and fifth?

Here is my code.

```
      <script>

      $(function (){      
             $(".botao-enviar").each(function (){
                 var selecionado=[];
                   var atual=[];

                   $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function (){
                       atual = $(this).val();
                       window.open(atual)        
                   });

             });

      });

      </script>
```

Comment: Are the five loads dependent on each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `setTimeout();`

pass index to `.each`

```
.each(function (i){
```

and use

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.open(atual) }, i* 1000); //change 1000 with duration you want
```

[**Simple Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/kgtstgkL/)

Comment: Yes, to work ... the problem is that it opens the fifth URLS after the stipulated time, I'd like to open the first and after the TimeOut he opened the second, and so on ... It would be necessary to use Loop?

Comment: @Rogerio You're welcoooooooooome  :).. Good Luck :) .